# I'm missing the References option in Project menu in VB 6.0

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, visual-sourcesafe

For the past year I've been working on some legacy code that was written in VB 6.0. Sometime in the last couple of days the "References" menu item disappeared from the Project menu drop-down on the menu bar. I've been using this version of the VB studio for the past year without any problems. The only thing that has changed recently is that I started using the VSS plug-in to check code in and out from within Visual Studio. This plug-in has been installed during the entire year I have been developing in VB 6. I just haven't been using it at all. Is this a problem anyone else has experienced and is their a known fix?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do a reset on Menu.

Right click on a toolbar -> customize... -> you should see a tab for the Menu -> you can reset it. This will bring the menu back to the state it was, when installed.

Comment: +1. To be precise: Right click on a toolbar, choose "customize" on the context menu. Choose "Toolbars" tab, highlight "Menu bar" checkbox and press Reset button. Alternatively go to "Commands" tab, choose "Project" then browse the list until you see References. Now you can drag-and-drop it back onto the Project menu. Click down on it with the mouse, then hold the mouse button down and drag the command back onto the menu.